# Check if point lies between two sets of co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates, point

I am creating a tower defence game and want to prevent the user placing towers on the path. The path is stored as an array of objects with properties `x` and `y`. I'll do a quick example to explain. Many "levels" (aka paths) are stored inside an array. Inside this array (so `Array[0]`, for example) is multiple objects, each detailing a point on the map that are then joined up to create a path:

```
levels = [
          [{x: 0, y: 0},         // When plotted:
           {x: 0, y: 50}],       // 0,0 to 0,50 creates a vertical line
           {x: 50, y: 100}],     // 0,50 to 50,100 creates a diagonal
          [{}] // more levels                                  
         ];
```

Due to the relative simplicity of the maths behind working out if a point is on a path where only one x/y value changes, I have a working version ([which you can find here](http://jsfiddle.net/AUL33/1/)).

Using the above path examples, you can test my fiddle to ensure you are following. Try the co-ordinates `0,35` which (should) return true. This is because x doesn't change, so we merely check if y is within the first and second point's y value, which it is. Working as intended :)

However, my problem is trying to find out if the tower is on a diagonal path. Both values change, so I need to figure out the maths to account for a "diagonal" of sorts. Using the second and third path points, a diagonal from `x:0`, `y:50` to `x:50`, `y:100` is formed, we can imagine a square around this diagonal. My (incorrect) function currently prevents any point in that square from being a tower, whereas it should only be the diagonal that can't be used.

Essentially, my current, incorrect function does this, with `a` being the start of the diagonal, and `b` the end point:

```
if(x is between a.x and b.x AND y is between a.y and b.y){
   build the tower
}
```

Sorry about all the words and lack of code, but the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUL33/1/) is a really stripped down version that should help understand. I'm primarily looking for the maths to achieve the functionality, I can write the code myself if you can help with the pseudo.

Comment: An easy answer would be to just check if the angle from the top left corner is the same. Just compare the value of (x2-x1)/(y2-y1) for the x's and y's of the path with the value of (xCurrent-x1)/(yCurrent-y1)..

Comment: @TimKuipers Hi tim, this seems like an easy way to do it! I experimented and it works, but just for a one pixel line. If the diagonal path is 30 pixels wide, how can I take that into account? Maybe a for loop trying 15 pixels to either side?

Comment: To check if a point lies within the two lines representing the borders of the path, you can check if the angle the one line makes with the point has a different sign than the angle with the other line. If the point is outside the path, it will be - say - to the right of both lines. So you can do `(x2-x1)/(y2-y1) > (x-x1)/(y-y1) && (x2'-x1')/(y2'-y1') > (x-x1')/(y-y1') || (x2-x1)/(y2-y1) < (x-x1)/(y-y1) && (x2'-x1')/(y2'-y1') < (x-x1')/(y-y1')`. This will be true if the point `(x,y)` lies outside of the area between the lines  `(x1,y1)-(x2,y2)` and `(x1',y1')-(x2',y2')` within the square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you consider the line equation: y = a * x + b

You can find a and b with two points.

Using the first point: (0,50)

```
50 = 0 + b
```

Therefore:

```
b = 50
```

Using the second point: (50, 100)

```
100 = 50 * a + 50
```

Therefore:

```
a = 1;
```

So the equation that determines if a point is on that line is:

```
y = 1 * x + 50
```

Examples:

point 1: (10, 60)

```
y = 1 * 10 + 50 = 60
```

This point is on the line.

point 2: (60, 110)

```
y = 1 * 60 + 50 = 110
```

This point is on the line but outside the boundaries of the two points. So you have to add checks for that.

I could go on with more points to check. But I hope the above will get you going.